# How to get last id after insert a value in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to get the last id inserted in my database

here is my code:

```
    $id = $_POST['c_id'];
    $var_id = $_POST['var_id'];
    $var_name = $_POST['variable_name'];
    $saveVar = "INSERT INTO ".$table_sub_var." 
    VALUES(NULL,".$var_id.",".$var_name.")";
    mysqli_query($connect,$saveVar);
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com also please learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Your code is not safe at all and your database could be hacked within a few seconds.

Comment: im using AJAX for that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysqli_insert_id()` method:

```
$id = $_POST['c_id'];
    $var_id = $_POST['var_id'];
    $var_name = $_POST['variable_name'];
    $saveVar = "INSERT INTO ".$table_sub_var." 
    VALUES(NULL,".$var_id.",".$var_name.")";
    mysqli_query($connect,$saveVar);

    $last_inserted_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect); // return last inserted ID
```

Comment: Im getting 0 when i tried to echo the $last_inserted_id

Comment: Then verify in database value is inserted or not

Comment: i found it now.. i forgot that the $var_name is a string..